# Perl issue with pattern replacement does not work for all strings

Tags: regex, perl

I'm working on a script which does pattern replacement for each file which matches a specific file type. I'm using the pattern replacement like this

```
s/$modifydata[$loop]/$modifydata[$loop+1]/g;
```

But this does not replace all the matches for some reason. Am I doing something wrong here, please help. I have been through couple of pages for pattern replacement but still im not able to find the issue. For the failing string i wrote a small test perl which seems to work im confused :-(

Input :-

```
[Project:CISCO_GATEWAY]
network-feed=TIG_Generated:
stream-window-start=0
stream-window-end=450
test-config=tig_generated no_disk_check
```

Expected output:-

```
[Project:CISCO_GATEWAY_WB]
network-feed=WB_TIG_Generated:
stream-window-start2=0
stream-window-end=450
test-config=tig_generated no_disk_check
```

Actual output :-

```
[Fusion-Project:BSKYB_GATEWAY_WB]
network-feed=TIG_Generated:
stream-window-start=0
stream-window-end=450
test-config=tig_generated no_disk_check
```

Perl Code Snippet :-

```
$modifydata[0]="TIG_";
$modifydata[1]="WB_TIG_";
$modifydata[2]="stream-window-start";
$modifydata[3]="stream-window-start2";
$modifydata[4]="CISCO_GATEWAY";
$modifydata[5]="CISCO_GATEWAY_WB";

open my $in,  '<',  $filteredfile      or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$filteredfile.tmp" or die "Can't write new file: $!";      
while( <$in> )
{
  for (my $loop=0; $loop < scalar(@modifydata); $loop=$loop+2)
  {          
    ($modifiedline = $_) =~ s/$modifydata[$loop]/$modifydata[$loop+1]/g;
    print "1[$_] 2[$modifiedline] 3[$modifydata[$loop]] 4[$modifydata[$loop+1]]\n"
  }
}
```

Sample test code works though :-(

```
my $oldstring = "network-feed=TIG_Generated:";
(my $newstring = $oldstring) =~ s/TIG_/WB_TIG_/g;

print "$oldstring","\n";
print "$newstring","\n";

[rajeguna@ukstbuild3 bin]$ ./tmp.pl
network-feed=TIG_Generated:
network-feed=WB_TIG_Generated:
```

Comment: Please provide the data that exhibits the problem, what output you got and what output you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$modifiedline = $_` should be done outside the loop. You are clobbering earlier modifications.